# ACF Field on CPT Slug

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I am a new user with acf and cpt.

I need to create a custom slug with an acf field like this:

mysite.com/cpt_title_slug/acf_field

and if possible tell me the file that I need edit, like functions.php

thank you!

Comment: You should open tickets with ACF and CPT?  Those are third party plugins and they don't always conform to exactly what WordPress would do or how it would do it.